# phpmyadmin gets autoupdated, sql mod

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, whm

Under mysql variables sql mode `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` has been removed. My server gets auto updated and the Value 
`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` returns.

Under Update Preferences Daily Updates has been set to Never Update, Operating System Package update is set to Never Update.

The server (phpmyadmin) gets updated regularly, and shows:

```
 ERROR No 1364 "Field 'coloumn_name' doesn't have a default value"
```

My server is from Godaddy

Kindly help..

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you currently running? Also what was the old version number, before the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit odd because the person (or software) that handles your updates should have updated the table structure for you, but it appears to be a pretty easy fix. phpMyAdmin has [an optional database](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) that enables advanced features. It sounds like that database structure wasn't updated when the rest of the phpMyAdmin code was updated.

Your situation is a bit odd in that the `column_name` column hasn't been changed since at least 2009, which basically means whatever version you were running must have been quite outdated.

In the `sql` folder (or a different folder if your current phpMyAdmin is still quite old, such as `scripts` or maybe `examples`), there are various .sql files which can help with updating your installation. You may wish to run `create_tables.sql`, but that won't always upgrade existing tables so, again depending on the versions involved, you may be better of dropping the table outright and running that script to create them. I don't see anything in the two current upgrade scripts that would affect `column_info`, so either that change is so old it's been removed or something else odd happened. You may also want to try doing it manually; if you go to edit that column's structure you can add a default of `''`.